# Adding events in FullCalendar - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to add an event when a day is clicked, but it's not working. I can't see a new event on the calendar, but I can see the "clicked" message I set. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title> Schedule </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fullcalendar.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#schedule').fullCalendar({
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

                $('#schedule').fullCalendar({'addEventSource', {title: "lesson", start: date}});
                alert("clicked");
            }})
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="schedule">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

firebug says invalid property id on the line with addEventSource.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little bracket heavy, try changing

```
.fullCalendar({'addEventSource', {title: "lesson", start: date}});
```

to

```
.fullCalendar('addEventSource', {title: "lesson", start: date});
```

If that still doesn't work try this...

```
.fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{title: "lesson", start: date}]);
```

Which is basically making the event an array instead of a single object.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I ended up making separate event objects. Thanks anyways!